# Problem with big numbers of fibonacci in assembly

Tags: assembly

My code is bellow the code work but for number more than 233 (as fibonacci numbers) when i print them the answers are mistake.. Why? Numbers 1,1,2,3,5,8,...,233 are ok but after 233 numbers are mistake

```
.model small
.stack 64
.data    
     B db ?    
     C db ?
     D dw ? 
     Array DB 20 DUP(0), '$'     
     Array_2 DB 8 DUP(0), '$'
     print_1    DB 13,10,"Please Enter A Number : 0< Number <13 --- And After 2 Digit Input '+' : Examlpe : 11+ :",13,10,"$"
     print_2    DB 13,10,"Fibonacci Series  : $" 
     Print_3    DB "  $"
.code
;****************************************************************
 main proc far 
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax    


    call RequestP                                            ;
    call Input                                               ;
    call Process                                             ;Callings
    call AnswerP                                             ;
    call Output                                              ;

    mov ax,4c00h             
    int 21h                  
   ;*********************************************************
         main endp  
RequestP proc near
    mov     AH, 9
    lea     DX, print_1                                    ;Printing the 
requestP
    int     21h    
    ret
RequestP endp 
  ;*********************************************************
Input proc near
    mov ax,0    
MyLoop0:
    mov ah,01
    int 21h  
    cmp al,'+'
    je  GoOut
    sub al,30h                                             ;Getting Users Number
    add B,al
    mov al,B
    mov ah,10
    mul ah
    mov B,al
    jmp MyLoop0
GoOut:    
    mov bl,10
    mov al,B  
    mov ah,0
    div bl
    mov B,al
    inc B      
    ret
Input endp  
  ;*********************************************************
Process proc near
    mov cl,B
    lea si,Array+1
    mov [si-1],1                                           ;Defining the Array
    mov [si],1 

    MyLoop:                      
    mov [si+1],0  
    mov bx,[si-1]  
    mov dx,[si] 
    mov bh,0
    add bx,dx                                              ;Processing Code&Putting in the Array
    mov [si+1],bx
    inc si     
    dec cl
    cmp cl,0
    jne MyLoop   
    ret
Process endp
  ;********************************************************* 
AnswerP proc near

      mov     AH, 9
      lea     DX, print_2                                  ;Printing the answerP
      int     21h  

      ret
AnswerP endp        
  ;*********************************************************
Output proc near
    mov cl,B
    lea si,Array
MyLoop2:   
   call PrintSpace    
   call GetDigit                                          ;Printing Digits
   inc si
   dec cl  
   cmp cl,0
   jne MyLoop2
ret
Output endp
  ;*********************************************************   
GetDigit proc near
  mov di,0  
  MyLoop3:
    mov ax,[si]
    mov ah,0
    mov bl,10
    div bl 
    add ah,30H                                             ;Printing Digits Proccess
    mov Array+di,ah
    inc di
    mov [si],al
    cmp al,0
    jne MyLoop3

 MyLoop4: 
    dec di   
    mov dl,Array+di
    mov ah,02                     ;Reversing the Digits
    int 21h 
    cmp di,0
    jne MyLoop4

    ret
 GetDigit endp 
  ;*********************************************************   
  PrintSpace proc near

      mov     AH, 9
      lea     DX, print_3                                  ;Printing Space
      int     21h

    ret
    PrintSpace endp
    end main
;***************************************************************
```

Comment: Why did you replace useful labels you likely had in your original code with "MyLoopX"??? Assembly is hard to read as it is - no need to make it harder (especially when you are asking for help). Also at first glance it does not look like your code support unlimited precision numbers which is required to compute large factorials and fibonacci numbers.

Comment: What assembler are you using, normally `mov [si],1` would require something to specify the size of the operand. For Microsoft assembler, the syntax would be `move byte ptr [si],1` . Also, you may want to start the array with 0 since fib(0) = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing everything as single bytes, so when the value exceeds 255, it fails.

Comment: For 16 bit unsigned integers (word), the max value is fib(24) = 46368. If the program is further modified to handle 32 bit unsigned integers (dword),  using a pair of registers, then the max value is fib(47) = 2971215073. The array size would need to be 48 dwords, if fib(0) = 0 is included.